# .NET PostSubmitter sends backslashes

Tags: c#, .net, json, http-post, backslash

I'm using C# to send JSON to a PHP-Script, like this:

```
string json = "{";
json += "\"prop\":\"some text\"";
json += "}";

PostSubmitter post = new PostSubmitter();
post.Url = "http://localhost/synch/notein.php";
post.Type = PostSubmitter.PostTypeEnum.Post;
post.PostItems.Add("note", json);
post.Post();
```

Of course I'll have to escape the inner quotes, but they get sended to the script! To make things worse: There is text, which already has quotation marks, so those must be escaped to be valid JSON. In this case I want the backslashes to be transmitted. Any idea to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not serialize the custom object to json result. That way you don't have to worry about the escaping, the framework would...  Here is an example using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) - [Convert objects to JSON in C# using JavaScriptSerializer](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Escape your backslashes `\\`:

```
json += "\\\"prop\":\\\"some text\\\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, thought PostSubmitter is from the .NET-framework, but it's third-party. Nevertheless: Turned out that this is a PHP-problem. If someone has a similar problem: Look for get_magic_quotes_gpc in PHP-docs.